# What is this sitting posture called?

Tags: word-request

[image]

The Wikipedia page of [sitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitting#Positions) doesn't list this kind of posture. Do you know what its name?

Comment: Are you sure they don't have *arm-draped-over-knee-with-one-foot-up-to-mid-calf-dangling-off-edge-of-cliff*?

Comment: In short, there is no word that specifically describes this posture. The woman is sitting. Anything else needs to be added in a descriptive phrase.

Comment: @userr2684291 I'm sure. Anyway, do you think *arm-over-knee sitting* a good name?